# How to achieve fixed side navigation in iOS?

Tags: ios

I am new to `iOS` development. I am developing an app which will contain fixed side menu on left side of all `ViewController`. When user will select any menu out of 5, selected menu will highlighted in different colour, but its later part.

**How do I achieve the fixed side menu?**

I am stuck on this. I search so many sites on Google but nothing helpful came out of it. Can anyone provide sample code?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: you want side menu like Facebook ?

Comment: just imagine tabbar on the left side...i want that type of side menu.

Comment: can you show any image for reference ?

Comment: I am unable to see this pic. This is not a link. Please make this as a link :)

Comment: it is just like facebook. but it will not be handled by navigation bar button. It should be fixed throughout the view controllers.

Comment: ya it'll not handle by navigation bar button i know. But user can swipe by finger or what ?

Comment: No. User can just select menu. It will not hide.

Comment: ok. you want on your home view on left side top corner a menu button, if user click that button then side menu will show on 75% on screen and again if user click that menu button again side menu view will be invisible ? like this or please share a image :)

Comment: U got it right sir, only there will not be any button which will open side menu. It will be always visible to user and will present on all view controllers.

Comment: Ya i got it. You want like tabbar view on left side. On which button u click that Viewcontroller is navigate but side menu is showing. right? i got it

Comment: Yes. now u got my point

Comment: can u provide some snippet code for reference?

Comment: Yeah, now i am implement that code. in between 5 mins i'll share my answer.wait :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code.

First create a `UIView` type class.

Write this code `TabbarController.h` Class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class TabbarController;
@protocol Tabbar_protocol <NSObject>

@required
-(void)First_viewController;
-(void)Second_viewController;
-(void)Third_viewController;
-(void)Fourth_viewController;
-(void)Fifth_viewController;

@end

@interface TabbarController : UIView // this is your UIView type class

-(void)CreateTabbarController;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSObject <Tabbar_protocol> *delegate;
@end
```

This code for `TabbarController.m` Class

```
#import "TabbarController.h"

@implementation TabbarController
@synthesize delegate;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
  {
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
      if (self) {
      // Initialization code
      [self CreateTabbarController];
   }
  return self;
}
-(void)CreateTabbarController
{
   UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [button1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 96)];
   [button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [button1 setTag:101];
   [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(TabbarBtn_Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self addSubview:button1];

   UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [button2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 96, 50, 96)];
   [button2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [button2 setTag:102];
   [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(TabbarBtn_Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self addSubview:button2];

   UIButton *button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [button3 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 192, 50, 96)];
   [button3 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [button3 setTag:103];
   [button3 addTarget:self action:@selector(TabbarBtn_Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self addSubview:button3];

   UIButton *button4 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [button4 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 288, 50, 96)];
   [button4 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [button4 setTag:104];
   [button4 addTarget:self action:@selector(TabbarBtn_Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self addSubview:button4];

   UIButton *button5 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   [button5 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 384, 50, 96)];
   [button5 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image5.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [button5 setTag:105];
   [button5 addTarget:self action:@selector(TabbarBtn_Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self addSubview:button5];
}
-(void)TabbarBtn_Action:(id)sender
{
  switch ([sender tag])
  {
    case 101:
        if (self.delegate != nil)
        {
            // code for changing your button color
            [self.delegate First_viewController];
        }
        break;

    case 102:
        if (self.delegate != nil)
        {
            // code for changing your button color
            [self.delegate Second_viewController];
        }
        break;

    case 103:
        if (self.delegate != nil)
        {
            // code for changing your button color
            [self.delegate Third_viewController];
        }
        break;

    case 104:
        if (self.delegate != nil)
        {
            // code for changing your button color
            [self.delegate Fourth_viewController];
        }
        break;

    case 105:
        if (self.delegate != nil)
        {
            // code for changing your button color
            [self.delegate Fifth_viewController];
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
  }
}
@end
```

In your all `ViewController.h` import this class & `ViewController.m` class call that delegate method.

```
#import "TabbarController.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <Tabbar_protocol>
{

}

// ViewController.m class

-(void)First_viewController
{
    // Navigate to FirstViewController...
}
-(void)Second_viewController
{
    // Navigate to SecondViewController...
}
-(void)Third_viewController
{
    // Navigate to ThirdViewController...
}
-(void)Fourth_viewController
{
    // Navigate to FourthViewController...
}
-(void)Fifth_viewController
{
    // Navigate to FifthViewController...
}
```

Like this you have to call in all 5 `ViewController`.

Comment: its working? If u face any problem then u can tell me :)

Comment: No its not working sir, I imported the class in my vc, created object of tabbarcontroller and called delegate method..but its not working.

Comment: i think u left some code. please check properly otherwise share your source code. After testing i will reply your question. its working fine with me. so please check otherwise share your code i'll check :)

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    TabbarController*tbc=[[TabbarController alloc]init];
    [tbc delegate];
    [tbc CreateTabbarController];
    [self First_viewController];
}
-(void)First_viewController
{
    UploadViewController*uvc=[[UploadViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentViewController:uvc animated:YES completion:nil];
}

Comment: i did something like this...sorry if this amature coding.

Comment: and one more thing i wanted to ask that, if i used this code in every vc,isnt there be  a lot of code duplication?

Comment: Please don't write anything in VieDidLoad. write only (void)First_viewController
{
    UploadViewController *uvc = [[UploadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UploadViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:uvc animated:YES];
}

Comment: whatever code i share please follow this , don't write any in ViewDidLoad method. And if you write this code in every VC there is no problem, you are creating custom tabbar and u have to call delegate method in every class.